# Count mismatch between source hive view and file extract generated through spark using scala

Tags: apache-spark, hive, extract

I have a hive view which is created on top of sub-query contains joins and unions between hive tables and some other views.

my requirement is to generate a extract in HDFS using spark/scala code.

Now, when i run my spark code, it generates a file with approx 21 millions records which are 60k more  records than source view returns on count(*) query which means records count mismatch between source & target even though it is 1-to-1 without any data transformation or manipulation.

So, if anyone has faced similar issue then please share the possible reason for it.

P.S. As of now, I don't have access to spark UI to check DAG

I tried to generate multiple part files but it didn't work.

One observation, data is pulled for specific date and there is no null for this field from source view but target has null for this field. I verified the same record in source on ID field but it has same value for the date field for which data is pulled. So, Bit confused now.

Comment: Can you share the queries ?